# Why is it "Not allowed to return a result set from a function"?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

Why when I create function, I get `ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

This is my query

```
delimiter //
create function tes_while()
returns int
begin
declare v = int;
set v = 0;
while v < 3 do
select v;
set v = v + 1;
end while;
return v;
end //
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

A function is usually applied on each row of a result set. Therefore it can not return multiple rows for one row. To assure that, you can only return a value from the function with the `return` command, not with the `select` like in your case. Remove the `select v;`, then it will work.